# Multiplicar Polinomios Python

Tags: algoritmos

estoy intentando implementar el siguiente algoritmo para multiplicar dos polinomios:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

x^m simplemente consiste en concatenar m ceros al principio de la lista que define a P(x)

llevo hecho lo siguiente:

```
def Multiply(pol1, pol2):

len_p1 = len(pol1)
len_p2 = len(pol2)

if (len_p1 == 1 and len_p2 == 1):
    return [pol1[0] * pol2[0]]
elif (len_p1 == 1 and len_p2 > 1):
    return pol2
elif (len_p1>1 and len_p2 ==1):
    return pol1

else:        
    m = min(len(pol1) // 2, len(pol2) // 2)
        
    pa= pol1[ : m]
    pb= pol1[m : ] 
    qa= pol2[ : m]
    qb= pol2[m : ]
    
    paqa= Multiply (pa,qa) 
    pbqb= Multiply (pb,qb)
    t = sub(sub(Multiply(add(pa,pb),add(qa,qb)),paqa),pbqb)

    return (add(add(ZeroLeft(paqa,2*m) ,ZeroLeft(t,m)), pbqb ))
```

Pero me devuelve un resultado que no es correcto y no veo que estoy haciendo mal.

pol1 y pol2 contienen listas de numeros

Comment: ¿Con qué datos pruebas? ¿Qué resultados obtienes? ¿Cual sería el resultado correcto=

Comment: pol1= [3,5,0,1]
pol2= [2,1,4,9,1] un resultado correcto seria  [6,13,17,49,49,9,9,1], pero obtengo [9,5,4,29,17,13,6]

Comment: El código publicado está incompleto. Faltan funciones como `add` y `sub`.

Comment: lo he añadido pero basicamente consisten en una suma y resta de listas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La implementación tiene un par de fallos:

- Los casos especiales en los que uno de los polinomios es de grado 1, están mal resueltos. Estás retornando en esos casos el otro polinomio, pero eso sólo estaría bien si el polinomio de grado 1 tiene su único coeficiente igual a 1. En general tendrás que multiplicar por ese coeficiente, con algo como:

  ```
  elif len(p1) == 1 and len(p2) > 1:
        return [p1[0]*c for c in p2]
  ```
- A la hora de separar el polinomio en dos trozos, has intercambiado lo que deberían ser `pa` y `pb`, así como `qa` y `qb`.

Creo que corrigiendo esos dos errores pasa a funcionar bien.

No obstante el código es farragoso de leer debido a expresiones como:

```
t = sub(sub(Multiply(add(pa,pb),add(qa,qb)),paqa),pbqb)
```

Propongo una solución orientada a objetos que define la clase `P` (de Polinomio) que implemente los operadores +, -, y * para hacer sumas, restas y multiplicaciones de polinomios. Y ya de paso voy a implementar el operador `>>` para permitir algo como `poli >> m` como equivalente a `ZeroLeft(poli,m)`

También implementaré el método `__str__()` para que cuando se haga `print(poli)` salga algo bonito y legible en vez de `<__main__.P object at xxxxx>`.

Esta es mi implementación:

```
class P:

  def __init__(self, *coefs):
    """El constructor admite una lista como parámetro, o bien los coeficientes
    separados por comas, es decir, tanto P(1,2,3) como P([1,2,3]) son válidos"""
    if type(coefs[0]) in (list, tuple):
      self.coefs = list(coefs[0])
    else:
      self.coefs = coefs

  def __repr__(self):
    """Representación del polinomio como cadena"""
    return f"P({', '.join(str(c) for c in  self.coefs)})"

  # Definimos los operadores
  # Suma (operador +)
  def __add__(self, otro):
    result =  [sum(n) for n in zip_longest(self.coefs, otro.coefs, fillvalue=0)]
    return P(result)

  # Resta (operador -) (que delega en el de suma usando self + )
  def __sub__(self, otro):
    return self + P([-c for c in otro.coefs])

  # Operador >>
  def __rshift__(self, n):
    return P([0]*n + self.coefs)

  # Y Multiplicación (operador *)
  def __mul__(self, otro):
    """Este operador implementa el algoritmo de Karatsuba"""
    p1 = self.coefs
    p2 = otro.coefs

    if len(p1) == 1 and len(p2) == 1:
      return P([p1[0] * p2[0]])
    elif len(p1) == 1 and len(p2) > 1:
      return P([p1[0]*c for c in p2])   # Corregido tu error
    elif len(p1) > 1 and len(p2) == 1:  
      return P([p2[0]*c for c in p1])   # Y aqui
    else:
      m = min(len(p1) // 2, len(p2) // 2)
         
      pb = P(p1[ : m])   # Corregido error, intercambiadas pb y pa
      pa = P(p1[m : ]) 
      qb = P(p2[ : m])
      qa = P(p2[m : ])
      
      # Observa la sintaxis más limpia al tener definidos operadores
      paqa = pa * qa
      pbqb = pb * qb
      t = (pa+pb) * (qa+qb) - paqa - pbqb

      # En la expresión final hay que poner más paréntesis de los que quizás
      # parezcan necesarios, debido a que el operador >> tiene muy
      # poca precedencia  (menos que la suma)
      return ((pa*qa)>>(2*m)) + (t>>m) + pbqb
```

Gracias a esta implementación podemos crear polinomios y operar con ellos usando una sintaxis intuitiva:

```
p1 = P(3,5,0,1,)
p2 = P(2,1,4,9,1)
print(p1*p2)

print(P(1,1)*P(1,1,1))
```

Y sale:

```
P(6, 13, 17, 49, 49, 9, 9, 1)
P(1, 2, 2, 1)
```

### Bonus

El algoritmo de Karatsuba, debido a su algoritmo "divide y vencerás" tiene una complejidad logarítmica, por lo que va a requerir en principio menos operaciones que la multiplicación clásica, que tendría una complejidad O(n^2) cuando los polinomios a multiplicar son ambos de grado n.

Sin embargo el algoritmo Karatsuba es recursivo, y la recursvidad tiene un alto coste en Python, pues implica llamadas a funciones, y las llamadas son costosas (hay que crear un marco de pila para cada una, preparar parámetros, destruir el marco de pila a la vuelta, etc.) Además mi implementación OOP, pese a su conveniencia por permitir una notación mucho más simple, involucra un montón más de llamadas "ocultas". Por ejemplo `pa+pb` en realidad se convierte en `pa.__add__(pb)`, y dentro de esa función aún hay más llamadas pues el resultado debe convertirse al tipo `P`, etc..

En definitiva, esta implementación de la multiplicación es *muy ineficiente* y sólo compensa si el tamaño de los polinomios a multiplicar es muy grande. He tenido la curiosidad de cronometrar cuánto tarda en hacer `pol1*pol2` del ejemplo, y ha tardado 133 µs

Puede parecer poco, pero es que la implementación "clásica", pese a su complejidad O(n^2), e implementada también en el contexto orientado a objetos, tarda sólo 7.3 µs

La implementación "clásica" sería ésta:

```
  def __mul__(self, otro):
    A = self.coefs
    B = otro.coefs
    m,  n = map(len, (A,B))
    prod = [0] * (m + n - 1);
    for i in range(m):
      for j in range(n):
        prod[i + j] += A[i] * B[j]
    return P(prod)
```

De hecho he probado incluso a multiplicar polinomios de grado 100 y el algoritmo de Karatsuba sigue tardando mucho mas que el clásico.

He tenido que llegar a polinomios de grado 500 para que los tiempos estén empatados. Por encima de ese grado, Karatsuba es más rápido.

Por tanto una implementación que tome lo mejor de ambos mundos podría ser:

```
  def __mul__(self, otro):
    grado = max(len(self.coefs), len(otro.coefs))
    if grado < 500:
      return self.mul_clasica(otro)
    else:
      return self.mul_Karatsuba(otro)
```

Es decir, la clase `P` implementa ambos métodos `mul_clasica()` y `mul_Karatsuba()`, pero el método `__mul__()` elige el que sea más rápido según el grado de los polinomios a multiplicar.

Observa por ejemplo que si el polinomio es de grado 800, usaría Karatsuba, pero ya que éste divide el polinomio en dos, de grados 400, e internamente usa `*` para multiplicarlos, se llamaría de nuevo a `__mul__()` que esta vez elegiría el algoritmo clásico. Así que usar Karatsuba no compromete a seguir usándolo recursivamente. Se usaría sólo en los primeros niveles de recursividad pero cuando los polinomios empiezan a ser pequeños se pasaría automáticamente al algoritmo clásico.

Comment: Que no te vea @Trauma usando ">>" como operador ...

Comment: @CandidMoe Jajaja! Bueno, creo que es bastante apropiado. Es un desplazamiento a la derecha rellenando con ceros por la izquierda...

Answer (score 0):

Como dijo @abulafia, el error está en el intercambio de las variables pa, pb, qa y qb.

Hice esa corrección y simplifique un poco el código, ya que el algoritmo presupone polinomios del mismo grado:

```
def Multiply(pol1, pol2):
    #   Condicion de termino para la recursión:
    if len(pol1) == 1:
        return [pol1[0] * pol2[0]]

    #   Si no es termino, dividir los polinomios.
    m = len(pol1) // 2

    pb = pol1[: m]
    pa = pol1[m:]
    qb = pol2[: m]
    qa = pol2[m:]

    paqa = Multiply(pa, qa)
    pbqb = Multiply(pb, qb)
    t = sub(sub(Multiply(add(pa, pb), add(qa, qb)), paqa), pbqb)

    return (add(add(ZeroLeft(paqa, 2 * m), ZeroLeft(t, m)), pbqb))
```

**Demo**

```
pol1= [1,1,0]
pol2= [1,1,1]
print(Multiply(pol1, pol2))
pol1 = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
pol2 = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
print(Multiply(pol1, pol2))
pol1= [3,5,0,1,0]
pol2= [2,1,4,9,1]
print(Multiply(pol1, pol2))
pol1=[0,1]
pol2=[0,1]
print(Multiply(pol1, pol2))
```

produce

```
[1, 2, 2, 1, 0]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
[6, 13, 17, 49, 49, 9, 9, 1, 0]
[0, 0, 1]
```