# Existe alguna forma de crear dunder methods en Python?

Tags: python

-Los dunder methods (special methods, magic methods, etc... metodos de la forma _ _ metodo _ _ ) son basicamente los responsables de la grandisima cantidad de azucar sintactica que presenta Python, que es en gran medida lo que hace que el lenguaje sea tan sencillo, pues con el titulo no me refiero a emplearlos y por ende sobreescribirlos, sino a crearlos desde 0 por mas dificil que sea, en caso de no ser esto posible, me gustaria que se me aclarara el por que...

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Cómo crear clases sin tener que escribir tanto?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/450135/c%c3%b3mo-crear-clases-sin-tener-que-escribir-tanto)

Comment: ¿Qué pretendes lograr?

Comment: Nada te impide crear un método que se llame `__ejemplo__()`, pero el hecho de ser dunder no lo convierte en "magico", pues no estará asociado a ninguna operación del modelo de datos. Si lo que quieres hacer es esto último, he escrito una respuesta explicando cómo podrías hacerlo, y por qué seguramente no deberías hacerlo.

Comment: @CandidMoe realmente no, aunque me llamo la atencion ese modulo, no lo conocia, gracias por el comentario ...

Comment: Te recomiendo que pases a la lecturas de los siguientes artículos: 
[ask] y 
[mre] y 
[help/on-topic] y 
[help/dont-ask]

Comment: Este tipo de preguntas enfocadas en la búsqueda de aclaraciones fomentan el estilo de discucion estas son bien recibidas en nuestro canal de chat we como indica la ayuda: ***Si tu motivación para hacer la pregunta es “Quisiera participar en una discusión acerca de ______”, entonces no debes preguntar aquí. Sin embargo, si tu motivación es “Quisiera que otros me expliquen ______”, entonces está bien. (Por supuesto las discusiones son bienvenidas en nuestro chat web en tiempo real).***

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Los dunder methods son "especiales" porque el propio intérprete Python los usa bajo ciertas condiciones. Forman parte de su "[modelo de datos](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html)" y por tanto de la especificación del lenguaje.

Cuando por ejemplo el intérprete encuentra `a+b`, lo que hará será invocar `a.__add__(b)`. Esa traducción de `+` en `__add__()` está "incrustada" en la propia implementación del intérprete Python.

Si lo que planteas es algo como, por ejemplo, definir un nuevo operador, llamémosle `??` de modo que ante una expresión como `a ?? b` automáticamente se vaya a ejecutar un dunder method, llamémosle `__doublequestion__()`, la respuesta corta sería que **no** es nada sencillo hacer eso. Y me explico.

Para poder hacer eso necesitarías:

1. Modificar el tokenizador léxico de la implementación python, por ejemplo la de la implementación en C (pero en realidad la de todas las implementaciones), de modo que detecte el nuevo token `??`
2. Modificar el parser de la implementación Python, para asignarle un significado por defecto a ese nuevo operador. También tendrías que asignarle una precedencia con respecto al resto de operadores que ya existen. ¿Se ejecuta `??` antes que ninguna otra cosa, como el operador `**` de exponenciación, o se ejecuta siempre el último, con los operadores de lógica a nivel de bits `&`, `|`, `~`?
3. Implementar esa operación "por defecto" para los tipos básicos en los que tenga sentido, o al menos implementar una operación por defecto que eleve la excepción `NotImplemented`
4. **La más importante**. Convencer a los desarrolladores Python de que es buena idea hacer todo eso. Que el operador `??` es necesario. Escribir un PEP detallando por qué, ejemplos de código que muestren cómo se hacían las cosas antes de que inventaras ese operador y cómo se harán después, demostrando que el lenguaje mejora en simplicidad o expresividad gracias a tu adición.

Si no haces 4, aunque todo lo anterior es *técnicamente* posible, acabarías con algo que no es Python, porque no sigue la especificación del lenguaje. Sería tu propio python de uso particular.

Por tanto, como ves, la cuestión no es si *es posible* sino si *merece la pena*. ¿para qué querrías hacer algo así? Ten en cuenta que el modelo de datos Python es muy rico y ya permite redefinir montones de operadores ¿se necesita en verdad uno nuevo? La comunidad de desarrolladores Python es bastante reacia a incluirlos y tiene que ser por muy buenas razones. Por ejemplo, ya ocurrió en el pasado con el operador  `@`, porque se pensó que podría ser útil para paquetes como `numpy` y otros de álgebra matricial, como una forma de representar el producto entre matrices (propuesto en el [PEP 465](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0465/), implementado finalmente en Python 3.5). Ese operador no está implementado en ninguno de los tipos estándar Python, pero está disponible para ser implementado en el método especial `__matmul__()`.

Comment: En respuesta a "para qué querrías hacer algo así?", es basicamente por curiosidad, aunque ciertamente como indicas, no vale la pena invertir mi tiempo en ello, buena respuesta ...

Comment: osea se no se puede crear un metodo dunder, ya que para eso se tendria que implementar en el *codigo fuente de python*, no es asi?

Comment: @Christian No... no exactamente. Puedes crear métodos dunder si con eso simplemente entiendes que son métodos cuyo nombre lleva `__` al inicio y `__` al final. Lo que pasa es que algunos de esos métodos tienen _nombre reservados_ por el propio intérprete, ya que son invocados cuando se usan ciertos operandos del lenguaje. Es esa asociación entre operandos y nombres especiales la que forma parte del intérprete. Si quieres crear un nuevo operador y asociarle un nuevo nombre especial, es entonces cuando tienes que modificar el fuente del lenguaje

Comment: @Christian Pero no necesitas tocar el fuente de python si lo único que quieres es implementar en tus propias clases algunos de los nombres especiales ya usados por Python. Por ejemplo, puedes escribir una clase que implemente `__add__()` y entonces podrás escribir en tu programa `a+b` si `a` y `b` son instancias de esa clase. Mira por ejemplo cómo implementé yo la clase "Polinomio" [en esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/448329/7123) de modo que sea posible operar con polinomios como si fuera cualquier otro tipo numérico.

Comment: @Christian como dice abulifa, podrias crear un dunder method, un simple metodo de la forma _ _ metodo_ _(), el punto esta en que no seria del todo 'especial', con lo cual, en caso de querer hacer un dunder method que el interprete empleara en caso de encontrarse con ese nuevo operador, palabra clave, etc (esto de las palabras clave es solo una suposicion, no me pareceria raro que python empleara de alguna forma los dunder methods o algo parecido para lidear con palabras clave, sino es asi,por favor corrijanme ) SI, tendrias que modificar el codigo fuente de python

Comment: @PySanti He ampliado la respuesta para poner un enlace al modelo de datos. Ahí tienes todos los métodos especiales y para qué se usa cada uno. En general es para _operadores_, si bien algunos operadores no son símbolos, sino palabras, como `in`. No obstante no hay métodos especiales para implementar palabras clave de control, como `if`, `while`, etc.. No obstante todo el manejo de iteradores que `for` hace "tras bambalinas", se basa en los operadores `iter()` y `next()` que se implementan también mediante dunder methods. También el acceso a elementos de arrays, propiedades de objetos...

Comment: Aunque es correcto lo que dices, sí que puedes crear nuevos _métodos mágicos_ para implementar nuevos _interfaces_ (aka _clases base abstractas_ ). Los _métodos mágicos_ tienen dos cometidos: 1) emular tipo de datos, que es lo que indicas, y 2) _customizar_ distintos comporamientos (descriptores, acceso a atributos, creación de clases y contextos, etc). Un ejemplo se puede ver con el modo de customizar el [contenedor array](https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/basics.dispatch.html#writing-custom-array-containers) de numpy.

Comment: Este tipo de preguntas enfocadas en la búsqueda de aclaraciones fomentan el estilo de discucion estas son bien recibidas en nuestro canal de chat we como indica la ayuda: ***Si tu motivación para hacer la pregunta es “Quisiera participar en una discusión acerca de ______”, entonces no debes preguntar aquí. Sin embargo, si tu motivación es “Quisiera que otros me expliquen ______”, entonces está bien. (Por supuesto las discusiones son bienvenidas en nuestro chat web en tiempo real).***